# Why child threads alive after the main threads are killed?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, signals

I have written a code where I have created two child threads from the parent thread.

Then, with receiving a signal from another terminal inside those child threads, I printed the `threadID` and exited the thread.

I have 2 questions.

1. I'm receiving the signal from the child thread. Why is it printing the `threadID` of the parent thread?
2. After killing the parent thread, how can be the child threads alive??

The Code :

```
void sig_handler(int signo)
{
    if (signo == 1){
        printf("%d\n", pthread_self());
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
}

void* doSomeThing(void* arg)
{
    printf("In function -> %d\n", pthread_self());
    if (signal(1, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("\ncan't catch SIGHUP\n");
    while(1)
        sleep(1);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("In function -> %d\n", pthread_self());
    char *ch1;
    pthread_t tid1, tid2;
    ch1 = "random";
    int ret1, ret2;

    ret1 = pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, &doSomeThing, (void *) ch1 );
    ret2 = pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, &doSomeThing, (void *) ch1 );

    while(1)
        sleep(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the image of the output given in terminal :

[image]

The first 3 lines are the 3 `threadID`s. 1st one is the Main `threadID`s, then the two secondary threads.

Then the `threadID`s printed from the following block of code.

```
if (signo == 1){
    printf("%d\n", pthread_self());
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Why is this happening???

Comment: `signal` doesn't really work with threads.

Comment: Does that mean the `pthread_self()` function is not giving the proper `threadID` ?? As it is called after receiving the `signal` ??

Comment: @JishnuBanerjee `pthread_self()` will give the thread id of the calling thread. But the real issue is that it's not possible to have per-thread signal handlers; signal handling is process wide. See an example in the linked man page on how to block signals.

Comment: The C standard says: "Use of this function [`signal`] in a multi-threaded program results in undefined behaviour."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signals are delivered to the *process*, not to individual threads. So, you can't have a signal handler just for one thread as you are doing here.
What you can do is block signals you are interested in using [`pthread_sigmask()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigmask.3.html) and let a dedicated thread handle signals using [`sigwait()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigwait.3.html), which is the most common way.

Comment: How does sig_handler() get called here exactly? I mean OP gets a different threadID each time sig_handler() gets called i.e. OP sent a signal. 

How does this particular program actually manage/ act against  those signals?

Comment: The signal(s) sent by OP isn't specific to a thread. It's process-wide. So, you can't be sure/know to which thread the signal is delivered to.
`pthreads(7)` says: "POSIX.1 distinguishes the notions of signals that are directed to the process as a whole and signals that are directed to individual threads. According to POSIX.1, a process-directed signal (sentusing kill(2), for example) should be handled by a single, arbitrarily selected thread within the process." That "arbitrary signal delivery" means any thread can receive the signal and call the signal handler and its threadID get printed.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you can only safely call async-signal-safe functions from within a signal handler.  From [the Linux `signal` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html):

> **Async-signal-safe functions**
>
> A signal handler function must be very careful, since processing
>   elsewhere may be interrupted at some arbitrary point in the execution
>   of the program.  POSIX has the concept of "safe function".  If a
>   signal interrupts the execution of an unsafe function, and *handler*
>   either calls an unsafe function or *handler* terminates via a call to
>   `longjmp()` or `siglongjmp()` and the program subsequently calls an
>   unsafe function, then the behavior of the program is undefined.

The linked man page has a list of functions that are safe to call from within a signal handler.  If the function is not on that list, it is *unsafe to call it*.  No exceptions.

Note that neither `printf()` nor `pthread_exit()` are on the list of async-signal-safe functions.

And calling `pthread_exit()` from within a signal handler creates several other problems:

- The thread that exits is generally not under any control.  In many cases, the signal can be delivered to *any* thread.
- The exiting thread can leave objects in an unknown state - a mutex can be left locked by a thread that no longer exists, for example.
- Any thread cleanup handlers [registered with `pthread_cleanup_push()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cleanup_push.3.html) will also be called from within a signal handler context.